# Rails Devise: custom login view depending on the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise with Rails for user authentication. In my controller I have before filter:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController  
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Now, when user tries to open a method called :new inside MyController, the login view will be displayed. I need a way to customize this login view specifically for that :new method call.

I've already generated devise view templates.

So, is there some way to customize sessions/new view depending on the previous url?

Comment: I have the same question as well... did you ever find a solution? The only solution I'm thinking of right now is to not use before_filter :authenticate_user!, and instead check for user_signed_in? in my "new" method, and redirect to a custom login view that I'll create separately.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new]
```

authenticate_user method call all method without new

Comment: Well I need this authentication, it's just I need to customize the login view specifically for that :new method :D